# Cache JSON string response from Spring RestController

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to cache the JSON string of a Spring RestController, instead of caching the Java object returned?

Comment: Cache it in the browser?

Comment: Ha! The truth is that I want to compare it with the updated one the browser will send.

Comment: I'd recommend using JSON PATCH (perhaps with Spring Sync) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could write an [interceptor](http://javapapers.com/spring/spring-mvc-handler-interceptor/) to trap all requests and use 1 of the techniques described [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/08/convert-inputstream-to-string-java-example-tutorial.html) to convert request into a String. Caching can be done using a hash map with key as session id and URL